# how to set constraints on a ternary relation

Tags: alloy

I have this model

```
 sig Factor {}
 sig Rule { rule : some Factor }
 sig RuleSet { rules : some Rule }
 sig EventRuleProperty {}
 
 sig Event {
       rulesets : some RuleSet,
       rule_properties :  rulesets -> Rule -> EventRuleProperty
}
```

How do I write a fact to restrict the rules in `Event.rule_properties` have to belong to `Event.ruleset`?

I declared as

```
rule_properties :  rulesets -> rulesets.rules -> EventRuleProperty
```

but got a syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered [there](https://alloytools.discourse.group/t/a-ternary-relation-question/312/2). Please ask such questions in a single place for Alloy users (here on at the Alloy forum) unless you don't get any answer for several days.